# unsubscribe html form using php and my sql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, formmail

I have an html form where people can subscribe to a mailing list. The form includes form validation and when the form is submitted, the data is stored in a database using My SQL.

Here is the code on the index.html page where the form is

```
  <form id="subscribe-form" action="send.php" method="post">
    <p id="status"></p>
    <div>
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <select class="uniform" name="title" id="title">
        <option>Please Choose</option>
        <option>Mr</option>
        <option>Mrs</option>
        <option>Miss</option>
        <option>Ms</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
      <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="phone">Contact Number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="title">How did you hear about us?</label>
      <select class="uniform" name="refer" id="refer">
        <option>Please Choose</option>
        <option>Google</option>
        <option>Yahoo</option>
        <option>Word of Mouth</option>
        <option>Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="news_updates" value="1" />
      I'd like to hear about the latest news and events updates</div>
    <div>
      <input class="button" type="submit" value=""/>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here is the code for send.php

```
<?php 

    include ('connection.php');

    $sql="INSERT INTO form_data (title,firstName, surname, email, phone, refer, news_updates)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[title]', '$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[refer]','$_POST[news_updates]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql, $connected))
      { 
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_close($connected);    
?>
```

I would like to make another html (unsubscribe.html) page where people can unsubscribe by entering their email address so that their email address would match the corresponding email that is in the database already and remove it from the My Sql database . 
I found this tutorial which was kind of helpful - 
http://www.phpsuperblog.com/php/delete-records-from-mysql-database-with-html-form-and-php/

and this is the form on my unsubscribe.html page.

```
   <form  id="unsubscribe_form" action="delete.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="email_remove">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email_remove" name="email_remove" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="" class="unsubscribe_btn">
  </div>
</form>
```

but when I enter method="post" in the unsubscribe form. The data from the form on the  subscribe / index.html does not get stored in My Sql, instead they come up as blank. 
So I am guessing I can't have two "post" method maybe??

If someone could guide me in the right direction that would be much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I don't quite follow, I'm afraid - do you mean that the subscribe form isn't working? Or is there a problem with the unsubscribe code?

Comment: Show us your `delete.php` code.

Comment: you have to run query to delete record where `email = $_POST["email_remove"]` in `delete.php`

Comment: Thank you  tereško for the mysql adivce. I will look into the tutorials. 

Hi andrewsi, When I added the unsubscribe form and fill out the subscribe form the data in my SQL database doesn't show up anymore, whereas it was before adding the "method=post" and action="delete.php" in the unsubscribe form. My unsubscribe form doesn't work too. I hope I make sense.

Thank you Rishi Kalia for the query advice.

Comment: got my unsubscribe form working actually :)! Now I just need to figure out why the data is not appearing anymore when i fill in the subscription form - will look into KarmicDice's advice about the POST method

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are at your learning stage. So, I will suggest you to have a check for POST method being called on the page which receives the post.

Example: in your subscribe.php
you should have :

```
<input class = "button" type = "submit" value = "Subscribe" name = "subscribe" />
```

in send.php

you must do:

```
if(!isset($_POST['subscribe'])
{
 header('location: subscribe.html');
}
```

You must use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for your pages.

If you could display your delete.php, perhaps I can edit this post and assist you further but, so far... A check is required and you can use as many forms as many you like (even on one page) but, make sure they all have different id/names.

Your delete.php script should be:

```
<?php
require ('connection.php');  // User require for important functions so that if not found, it throws fatal error
$email = $_POST['email_remove'];
// Check for isset POST
$query = "DELETE from form_data WHERE email = '".$email."'";
if(mysql_query($query)){ echo "deleted";} else{ echo "fail";} 
?>
```

your delete.php seems OK to me.

Can add the following to Line 2
    echo "";
    print_r($_POST);

and post array in comments?

Comment: Hi KarmicDice thank you for the POST advice and tips about having as many forms as you like. Yep I am still at my learning stage so it's really helpful to know. 


This is my delete.php code
<?php 




include ('connection.php');
$email = $_POST['email_remove'];

$query = "delete from form_data where email = '".$email."'";
if(mysql_query($query)){
echo "deleted";}
else{
echo "fail";}

?>

Comment: Thanks KarmicDice for the feedback again. I changed my submit button in my subscribe.php to this 
`<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="submitform"/>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="" class="button"/>`
and added this the my send.php
`if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'submitform')'`

Comment: The subscribe form and my sql database is working now :)! but I found out my form_validation.js file was causing the problem too. So I took it out and now I don't have any form validation :(. I think this function `$("#contact-form").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` from the form_validation file is interfering with the submitform in the send.php? 
   `

Comment: If the solution worked, please mark at the Tick next to my answer? So that others can see the solution?